# Material-ui Hover

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

sorry if the communication is a bit poor, I'm using a translator.
My question is the following:
Can I do this in Material-Ui?

````
.boxspecial:hover{
  .titlelong{
      // css
   }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add inside your component with class `.boxspecial` the below (please note `sx` will work when you use it in another MUI component):

```
sx={{
    ":hover .titlelong": {
      // Your css here
    }
  }}
```

For example using the MUI `Box`:

```
<Box class='boxspecial'
    sx={{
      "&:hover .titlelong": {
        backgroundColor: "orange"
      }
    }}
  >
    <span class='titlelong'>Some text</span>
</Box>
```